# Pass `Array.prototype.includes` to callback without wrapping it in an anonomous function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback

Why do I need to wrap `animals.includes` in an anonymous function for the following ES6 js code to work as expected?

```
const animals = ["ape", "dog", "pig"]
const nouns = ["car", "planet", "apple", "dog"]

const hasPulse = nouns.some((n) => animals.includes(n))

console.log(`Heartbeat ${hasPulse ? '' : 'not '}detected!`)
```

If I unwrap animals.includes it throws a type error.

```
// this fails with TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
const hasPulse = nouns.some(animals.includes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the incompatibility between how `Array.prototype.some()` calls it's callback and how `Array.prototype.includes()` expect arguments.

The full definition of `[].includes()` is:

```
[].includes(thingToSearch, startSearchFrom);
```

For example, if you do:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].includes(1,3); // false
```

It would return `false` even though the array clearly includes `1`. This is because you told it to start searching from element `3` so `.includes()` only looked at `4` and `5` and could not find `1`.

The full definition of `[].some()` is:

```
[].some(function (item, index, theArray) {}, this);
```

So the `.some()` will pass the index of the current item to the callback you pass to it. For example if you do:

```
[10,20,30,40,50].some((x,y) => y == 2); // 30
```

It would return `30` because he first time `.some()` loops over the array it passes `10` to `x` and `0` to `y`. The second time it passes `20` to `x` and `1` to `y`. And the third time `y` will be `2` so `y == 2` is true so it returns the value where it is `true` which is `30`.

Now you can see that what `.some()` passes as the second argument and what `.includes()` expects as the second argument have different meanings.

The `.some()` method will pass the loop index while the `.includes()` method expect the second argument to tell it where to start searching.

So if you do:

```
const animals = ["ape", "dog", "pig"];
const nouns = ["car", "planet", "apple", "dog"];

nouns.some(animals.includes);
```

1. .. it would search for `car` in  `ape,dog,pig`,
2. .. then it would search for `planet` in `dog,pig` (remember index is now 1 so you are telling `.includes()` to ignore `ape`)
3. .. then it would search for `apple` in `pig` (index is now 2 so `.includes()` ignores `ape` and `dog`)
4. .. then it would search for `dog` in an empty array which of course it would not find.

Sure, there may be some algorithm where you want to do this. But I don't think this is what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You could **not** take

```
const hasPulse = nouns.some(Array.prototype.includes, animals);
```

with `thisArgs`, but unfortunately [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) features a second parameter `fromIndex`, which is handed over by the index and destroys the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a context issue, you should bind the includes function to the nouns array for it to work the way you want it to. The reason why the code you have is not working as you expect it is because when you pass the includes function to the some, it is not executed on the array (this is either undefined or is set to the window object in the browser). Here is the working example

```js
const animals = ["ape", "dog", "pig"]
const nouns = ["car", "planet", "apple", "dog"]

const hasPulse = nouns.some(animals.includes.bind(nouns))

console.log(`Heartbeat ${hasPulse ? '' : 'not '}detected!`)
```

Comment: "Try this" is not a good way to answer a question, even if you post working code. You should explain what the problem was and how your code solves it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've updated my answer and included more details

Comment: It should be `.bind(animals)`

Comment: @Barmar if you .bind(animals) I don't think it will function correctly. There is a dog in nouns but that will not be found

Comment: But `animals` is the array you want to search with `includes()`.

Comment: `nouns` is the array you're processing with `some()`.

Comment: Take `dog` out of `animals` and your code will still say `heartbeat detected`

Comment: This cannot work as JS array methods also pass the element's index, which is passed as the second argument to the `includes` function as the `searchStart`. Also, the includes must be bounded to the `animals` array as, in this case, it's searching into `nouns` which means is always returns `true`. *(Sorry for bad English, I'm French)*

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how a Javascript method "knows" which object it was attached to when called: its `this` reference.

`includes` might be implemented something like this (hypothetical example):

```js
Array.prototype.includes = function includes(couldBeMember) {
  for (const member of this) {
    if (member === couldBeMember) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

`animals.includes(argument)` passes `argument` to `Array.prototype.includes`, but also sets its `this` to `animals` during the call. Just referencing `animals.includes` and passing that elsewhere, is no different than passing `Array.prototype.includes`; if it is ultimately called (inside `some`) without reference to `animals`, it won't get `animals` set as its `this`.

To create a function `includes` that "remembers" its `this` is `animals`, no matter where the function by itself is passed, you have to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) it to `animals`: `animals.includes.bind(animals)` (or `Array.prototype.includes.bind(animals)` or `[].includes.bind(animals)`).

```js
const animals = ["ape", "dog", "pig"]
const nouns = ["car", "planet", "apple", "dog"]

const hasPulse = nouns.some([].includes.bind(animals))
```

This isn't a whole lot cleaner than just using an arrow function (or "lambda"), but hopefully answers your question.

If you like the idea but want to clean it up, you could create a freestanding `bind` that does something like so:

```js
function bind(self, method, ...args) {
  return self[method].bind(self, ...args);
}

const hasPulse = nouns.some(bind(animals, "includes"))
```

(There's also at least one proposal out there to create an operator that performs the equivalent binding, something like `animals::includes`, but I don't believe that's finalized yet last I checked so the syntax might change or it might not end up supported.)

Answer (score -2):

The some() method tests if one element or more in the array passes the test implemented in the provided function and returns a Boolean value indicating the result.

```
const hasPulse = nouns.some((n) => animals.includes(n))
```

The second alternative won't work.
Array.includes uses a second parameter (fromIndex) which is received from the calling function as index and omits values to be checked by that function.

Comment: how is it different from op's first approach?